# How to properly show a fraction in a cell Word 2010

Tags: ms-word, cell, equation

I'm struggling to make fractions look right in a cell. If I insert an equation in a cell and build a fraction, the top and the bottom is cut as if there were hiddens margin in the cell, but there aren't. If I increase the cell height, it doesn't solve the probleme either.
How can I manage to make my fractions look right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting *Exactly* (in point size) the **line spacing** was the problem (this parameter is in *Paragraph* under *Line Spacing* in Word), the issue was not related to the fraction being inside a cell or not.